# Overload print value of class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I can overload the return value for example on `cout` function?
I have for example this class :

```
class Xxx
{
   string val = "3";
}
```

Now I would like to return `"3"` on `cout` without other method.
I want that :

```
Xxx myVar;
cout<<myVar;
```

prints `"3"` as its result.

Comment: Have you tried researching? Here's a hint, and this isn't C at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to overloas `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, T)`. Here, `val` is made public for simplicity:

```
class Xxx
{
 public:
   std::string val = "3";
}

#include <ostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Xxx& x)
{
  return o << x.val;
}
```

Then

```
Xxx x;
std::cout << x << std::endl; // prints "3"
```

This approach means you can also stream instances of `Xxx` to types of output stream other than `std::cout`, for instance, files.

Comment: Lately I've been using `template <typename CharT> std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT>& os, const Xxx&)` where possible. Do you think this is worth bothering with?

Comment: @BoBTFish I would say it is definitely worth it, why limit oneself to `char`. Probably too much for OP to handle at the moment though.